# Cannot open terminal in VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I need to open a terminal in Visual Studio. I've tried

- Re-installing VS Code
- The usual Windows shut down / restart
- Run vs code as admin
- Change settings.json file

I didn't change anything but something is broken in my code Editor help needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Windows** users:

1. **Open PowerShell terminal (windows button + r -> cmd)**
2. **Right click on the title bar**
3. **Open properties**
4. **Check the "Use legacy console" checkbox**

For Linux users:

1. Open VS Code
2. Ctrl + ,
3. Search env and find Terminal > Integrated> Env: Linux
4. Add this "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true to the object body

Answer (score -1):

Press **ctrl + `**. It might work, and if it doesn't, try reinstalling the vs-code again and then try the above key combo again.

Comment: I'm not getting your problem, please clear that out. Was my answer helpful?

Comment: No that's not. Check the answer below if you once face this issue :)